# Checkout Process is Stuck and loader never disappears in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, cache

I have created a replica of production environment,but on dev environment checkout process is stuck and loader(shipping,payment and review) never disapears but everything works fine on production environment.I tried almost every solution but nothing worked.I cleared cache and reindex,but issue still persists.
Production URL: https://thesparescompany.com
Dev URL: http://103.86.181.76/thespares/

The code based and DB is same,so ideally there is no code level issue and no console error also.Any guide to resolve the issue would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Something conflict with your superfish js.

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).superfish is not a function
    at HTMLDocument. (superfish.js:123)
    at fire (jquery-1.9.1.js:1037)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.9.1.js:1148)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.9.1.js:433)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.9.1.js:103)
```

Here is possible solution:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818988/typeerror-jquery-superfish-is-not-a-function-ul-sf-menu

[image]

Comment: the same error is on production also but there its working as expected so i ignored this error message..

Comment: Fix this first, will fix other maybe

Comment: when the error is same on both env,but at one place its working and on other its not,then this error is not the root cause..still i will fix it

Comment: Did you check php error_log?

Comment: yes,i did check the error and access logs but there is no error.

Comment: <div class="loader" id="loader_checkout-shipping-method-load"></div> this div tag is appended but its get removed on prod but not on dev url..

Comment: As per my understanding, php return success then this loading div will disappear.

Comment: as the code base is same,its not something related with the code..would u tell me what could be probable fix/cause for this issue..?and if u see correct shipping method and payment methods are getting listed but only the loader keeps loading..